# Swift 2.0 enum - 'willSet' equivalent? or is there a way to catch when the value is changed?

Tags: enums, swift2, ios9

I want to have a static variable in an enum that holds it's previous value and updates when the value is changed.  Not sure if this is possible.

```
enum Level {
  case LUNCHROOM
  case HALLWAY
  case LIBRARY
  case COUNT

  static var previous:Int?

  init() {
    self = .LUNCHROOM
    setPrevious()
  }

  private func setPrevious() {
      if Level.previous == nil {
          Level.previous = self.hashValue
      }
  }
}
```

If I assign the enum like this:

```
var x = Level()
Level.previous  //equals 0 now
```

BUT if I was to assign like this:

```
var x = Level.LUNCHROOM
Level.previous  //equals nil
```

Because I explicitly made x = .LUNCHROOM it skips the init() method.

I guess what I'm asking is there an equivalent to **willSet {}** or another way to catch when the value is changed so I can send it to a method to update the **"previous"** value?

Answer (score 0):

When you ask "is there... [a] way to catch when the value is changed", the issue is that there seems to be a misunderstanding in what is happening.

`var x = Level.HALLWAY` **assigns** an enumeration value (an instance of the `Level` Enumeration type) to `x`.

`x = .LUNCHROOM` **assigns** a different enumeration value to the variable `x` - this is a brand new and separate instance of the `Level` enumeration type, it is not modifying or acting on the `.HALLWAY` instance that was previously assigned.

Given this, the answer is "no", there is not a way to "catch the value when it is changed" because the value is not being *changed*, a brand new instance is being **assigned**.

To accomplish what you are asking via enums, the most obvious option that comes to mind would be to assign new enumeration values via a mutating instance method, i.e. once you have an enum variable, instead of assigning new values to it you could call a `moveTo(_:)` instance method on it, like this:

```
enum Level {
  case LUNCHROOM
  case HALLWAY
  case LIBRARY
  case COUNT

  static var previous: Level!

  mutating func moveTo(level: Level) {
    Level.previous = self
    self = level
  }
}

var x = Level.HALLWAY
Level.previous  // nil

x.moveTo(.LUNCHROOM)
Level.previous  // Level.HALLWAY
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift enums are special because they can be created without calling an initialiser.

If you want to observe all creations of your enum you have to make a convention for yourself: For example instantiating them by calling a specific method or in this case an `init`:

```
enum TestCase {
    case One, Two
    init(_ x: TestCase) { self = x }
}

// when (re)assigning always use the convention
var x = TestCase(TestCase.One)
x = TestCase(TestCase.Two)
```

But if you only want to observe a variable you can add a property observer anywhere at any time: For example in the scope of a function

```
func someFunc() {
    var x: TestCase {
    didSet{
        // update code
    }
    }
    x = TestCase.One
    x = TestCase.Two
}
```